# Battery Saver setting not sticking

Tags: settings, battery

In Android Settings, under Battery, there is a setting called ***Battery Saver***.

On multiple devices, changing that setting to `On` simply results in it changing back to `Off` within a few seconds.

What is causing this, and how can it be corrected?

Comment: Do you happen to be plugged into the charger while testing this?

Comment: @TurboFool Good question; the answer is "no".

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem on my Nexus 6, unless it's charging. What phone do you have, out of curiosity?